# MongoDBでリプライの合計を取得したい

Tags: mongodb

id,replyと言うカラムを持つテーブルhogeがあります
replyはリプライ先のidが入っていて、リプライ先がなければnullです
以下のようなデータがあったとします。

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "reply":null
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "reply":"1"
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "reply":"2"
},
{
    "id":"4",
    "reply":"1"
}
```

これを取得する時に以下のように自信に対するリプライの合計も取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "reply":null,
    "replyCount":2
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "reply":"1",
    "replyCount":1
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "reply":"2",
    "replyCount":0
},
{
    "id":"4",
    "reply":"1",
    "replyCount":0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

サンプルデータ：
（注）MongoDBテーブルには必ず「_id」フィールドが入っていますが敢えて表示しないようになっています。質問の「id」フィールド名をそのまま使います。

```
db.hoge.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5841f3d27261c6e2fca154d4"), "id" : "1", "reply" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5841f3d27261c6e2fca154d5"), "id" : "2", "reply" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5841f3d27261c6e2fca154d6"), "id" : "3", "reply" : "2" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5841f3d27261c6e2fca154d7"), "id" : "4", "reply" : "1" }
> db.hoge.find({}, {_id: false})
{ "id" : "1", "reply" : null }
{ "id" : "2", "reply" : "1" }
{ "id" : "3", "reply" : "2" }
{ "id" : "4", "reply" : "1" }
```

基本的に以下二つの結果を合流することになります。「id」と「reply」の項目：

```
> db.hoge.find({}, {_id: false, "id": true, "reply": true}).sort({"id": 1})
{ "id" : "1", "reply" : null }
{ "id" : "2", "reply" : "1" }
{ "id" : "3", "reply" : "2" }
{ "id" : "4", "reply" : "1" }
```

さらにこの集計結果。
（注）「_id」フィールドは集計結果のキーです。今回ご質問のサンプルデータにあるリプライ元の「id」フィールドと同じ意味です。

```
> db.hoge.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$reply", "replyCount": {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$match: {"_id": {$ne: null}}}, 
    {$sort: {"_id": 1}}])
{ "_id" : "1", "replyCount" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "2", "replyCount" : 1 }
```

つまり、方法の一つは「この２つの結果をクライント側（アプリケーション側）でマージする」です。

もう一つは$lookupの集計ステージと集計配列$sizeのオペレーターを適用してこのように出力する方法です。

```
> db.hoge.aggregate([
    {$project: {"_id": false, "id": "$id", "reply": "$reply"}}, 
    {$lookup: {from: "hoge", localField: "id", foreignField: "reply", as: "replies"}}, 
    {$project: {"id": "$id", "reply": "$reply", "replyCount": {$size: "$replies"}}}] )
{ "id" : "1", "reply" : null, "replyCount" : 2 }
{ "id" : "2", "reply" : "1", "replyCount" : 1 }
{ "id" : "3", "reply" : "2", "replyCount" : 0 }
{ "id" : "4", "reply" : "1", "replyCount" : 0 }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。一つ目の方法で条件を指定する時は、最初のクエリは通常通り条件を指定して検索、その結果をjavascriptのmapでid配列に変換→二つ目のクエリの$matchで$inを使えばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 最適な方法は、使われているプログラミング言語やデータ量によります。stackoverflow のQ&Aの仕組み通り、追加の質問は別途、新しい「質問」とすることをお勧めします。その際、その2つの マージするカーソルの内容とソート順序、使いたいプログラミング言語を明記してください。

「データ量」ということは主にメモリー内でソートができるかできないで区切られている。

Comment: 分かりました
別にするか考えてみます